# Hot recirculating loop connection

Tags: water-heater

My old tank only had one hook up for the recirculation pump. My new tank has a hot and cold opening for the receipt recirculation loop. not sure how I should hook it up?

Comment: Are you quite sure your new tank is set up for a recirculation loop? That sounds more typical of a heat exchanger as might accept solar or boiler heated fluid, or be used to heat a small radiant zone. If you plug one of those two and blow in the other, does air come out the other water inlets/outlets, or are those two only connected to each other, internally?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.